Database import fails in Android because of notNull
So, I have these entities
@Entity(
    tableName = "emojis",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = GroupEntity::class, parentColumns = ["group_id"], childColumns = ["group_id"], onDelete = ForeignKey.NO_ACTION),
        ForeignKey(entity = SubGroupEntity::class, parentColumns = ["subgroup_id"], childColumns = ["subgroup_id"], onDelete = ForeignKey.NO_ACTION)
    ]
)
data class EmojiEntity(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "hex")
    val hex: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    val desc: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "skin_tone")
    val skinTome: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "group_id")
    val groupID: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "subgroup_id")
    val subGroupId: Int
)

@Entity(tableName = "groups")
data class GroupEntity(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "group_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "group_name")
    val name: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "subgroups")
data class SubGroupEntity(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "subgroup_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "subgroup_name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "group_id")
    val groupId: String
)

I have an external database file that I'm trying to import. It is failing with these errors.
// Expected
//  TableInfo{name='emojis', columns={description=Column{name='description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, hex=Column{name='hex', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'},    skin_tone=Column{name='skin_tone', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, group_id=Column{name='group_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'},  subgroup_id=Column{name='subgroup_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}},  foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='groups', onDelete='NO ACTION +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[group_id], referenceColumnNames=[group_id]},ForeignKey{referenceTable='subgroups', onDelete='NO ACTION +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[subgroup_id], referenceColumnNames=[subgroup_id]}], indices=[]}
// Found
//  TableInfo{name='emojis', columns={description=Column{name='description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'},hex=Column{name='hex', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'},  skin_tone=Column{name='skin_tone', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, group_id=Column{name='group_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, subgroup_id=Column{name='subgroup_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='groups', onDelete='NO ACTION +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[group_id], referenceColumnNames=[group_id]},ForeignKey{referenceTable='subgroups', onDelete='NO ACTION +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[subgroup_id], referenceColumnNames=[subgroup_id]}], indices=[]}

Create statement from SQLite Explorer
CREATE TABLE emojis (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    hex TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    skin_tone TEXT,
    group_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    subgroup_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups (group_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subgroup_id) REFERENCES subgroups (subgroup_id)
  )


Not sure why room is not detecting non-null types.
UPDATE
After further testing, I have found out the same schema is working in my Pixel 7 pro but not in my Redmi A1

Well, apparently in your database file the columns are nullable and in your entity they are not, hence the error. What exactly is the question here?

@Leviathan, Please check the updated question.

Try changing the description field in the EmojiEntity.
from:
@ColumnInfo(name = "description")
val desc: String
to:
@ColumnInfo(name = "description")
val desc: String?

It's not just the description but other fields that are supposed to be non-null but are nullable. In particular, the id field should never be nullable. Your answer is suggesting the opposite of what the OP is trying to achieve: to make fields non-null.

I have attached the screenshot. In the DB all these fields are non null.

The ISSUE(s)
Room expects versus what Room has found (the imported database), for the emojis table:-
name='description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'
name='description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'

due to val desc: String the Room version expects TEXT NOT NULL.
The imported database, contrary to description TEXT NOT NULL is in fact description TEXT  (as per the create sql included in the question).

name='hex', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'
name='hex', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'

similar to description

id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'
id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'

similar to description BUT the type affinity is INTEGER

skin_tone=Column{name='skin_tone', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'
skin_tone=Column{name='skin_tone', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'

OK

group_id=Column{name='group_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'
group_id=Column{name='group_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'

similar to id

subgroup_id=Column{name='subgroup_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'
subgroup_id=Column{name='subgroup_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'

similar to id/group_id

Clearly the create statement shown is not what has been used to create the emojis table of the imported database.



Suggested Fix Methodology

Room is, as can be seen, unforgiving in what it expects. However the simplest solution is to let Room determine the schema of the imported database.

This is typically simpler than trying to understand the nuances of how Room interprets an @Entity into the resultant schema.

That is after:-

creating the @Entity annotated class(es) AND ,

note that if you want a column to be nullable then use ? after the field type e.g. : String? instead of : String


after specifying the class(es) in the entities parameter of the @Database annotation AND,
after successfully compiling the project

To inspect the java(generated) (visible via the Android View) to locate the class(file) that is the same name as the @Database annotated class but suffixed with _Impl.
Within this class there will be a method name createAllTables, this has the EXACT SQL for the creation of the table(s) that Room expects (room_master_table can be ignored as this will be created when the database is built)
Considering that the tables already exist, and assuming that they are populated, you need to convert the existing tables to those as per Room's expectations. This can be done in the SQLite tool by running various SQL statements.
On a per table basis (due to Foreign Keys the ORDER of handling the tables is important, creation of the groups and subgroups should be before the creation of the emojis table, whilst the emojis_original table should be dropped before the groups_original and subgroups_original are dropped), you could:

backup the database file
rename the existing table(s). e.g. ALTER TABLE emojis RENAME TO emojis_original;
create the replacement table(s) using the SQL as copied from the respective statement in the generated java.
Load the data from the original table into the replacement table. The simplest form being INSERT INTO emojis SELECT * FROM emojis_original

if a replacement column was nulllable (i.e. NOT NULL was NOT specified) and that column is not nullable and no default value has been specified and an original value was null then the above would fail. The fix could be to specify all the individual columns rather than * e.g. INSERT  INTO emojis (id,hex,description,skin_tone,group_id,subgroup_id) SELECT id, ifnull(hex,'00'), ifnull(description,'NOT GIVEN'),skin_tone,group_id,subgroup_id

NOTE that group_id and subgroup_id being Foreign Keys, should not be null AND that the groups and subgroups tables should be created and populated before populating the emojis table.




delete (DROP) the renamed tables (in the correct order)
Optionally, but suggested VACUUM.
Close/Save the converted database file.

it is suggested that you check that the saved file is as expected (suggest closing and restarting the SQLite tool to do so).


replace the the database to be imported with the converted database file.


I have attached the screenshot.
